# Agregar un body a una peticion con Guzzle

Tags: laravel, api, postman, graphql, guzzle

En postman tengo una api que funciona bien si hago la petición por ahí. Pero al momento de hacerla con guzzle me sale un error 500 del servidor.

Creo que el problema es como le envio la data.

Ya intente de esta forma.

```
 $arrayResponse = 'mutation{
      createUser( PlatFormID: \"452\", lang: \"es\")
      {
         name: \"juanito\"
      }
 }';

 $response = $this->client->post($base.'/graphql', 
    [
        'headers' => $headers,
        'body' => $arrayResponse
    ]
 );
```

En postman tengo lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe destacar que la url esta bien y los headers ya los compare y están exactamente iguales.

Intente pasando la información con ***form_paramsy json*** pero no recupero la respuesta esperada del api.

Comment: Probaste pasarlo como un array? http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#post-form-requests

Comment: Si lo escribo como array ya no podre pasar directos los querys de graphql